# Ensuring Sequential Fields are Filled In MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, triggers

I'm seeking to configure a table in MySQL that will allow me to enforce an order of field entry.

e.g. Presume a table which includes the following fields

Stage1Timestamp, Stage1AuthorizedBy, 
Stage2Timestamp, Stage2AuthorizedBy, 
Stage3Timestamp Stage3AuthorizedBy

Where the Timestamps are datetimes to be automatically filled when the AuthorizedBy information is added. (foreignkeys or codes or whatever. **That** detail is irrelevant.)

What I'm thinking is along these lines:

On definition of AuthorizedBy, set the associated datetime to Now if immediately preceding stage's AuthorizedBy and Timestamp are filled. Otherwise, blank the current value.
If either Timestamp or AuthorizedBy value is being blanked out, delete the peer and immediate superior.

This should work fine if MySQL will chain triggers. Does that work? Other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you use InnoDB, foreign key constraints are built to check stuff like this for you. Split it up to 3 tables, add keys from stage 2 to stage 1 and from stage 3 to stage 2, and use `ON DELETE SET NULL` to achive desired behaviour.

[Foreign Key Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. That was the primary other way I was looking at, as it happens, but it seems to me that this should also work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should solve this on the application layer, however here is a DB solution, no need for triggers - just foreign keys. All `CreatedAt` fields are not null, default to `now()` -- in MySQL it is called **[TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)**.

[image]

This is OK only for processes which will **not change** over time.

Comment: Are you suggesting using a foreign key per stage, or a row per stage? I'm not positive I followed your meaning.

Clarification: I'd like to maintain two timestamps: creation and update. I left that out for simplicity of explaining the question, but that's why I was using triggers. For some reason, according to the docs, only one Timestamp can auto-update and only one field can auto-increment per table. 

I certainly _could_ solve this app level, but I wanted to have a db that could maintain data integrity, even during development of various applications.

Comment: @The Nate, I suppose you are talking about the `Action` table? You can get latest time stamp by using `greatest(CreatedAt,CreatedAt_1,CreatedAt_2 ...)` from join. Each stage would insert into it's own table, so the `Action` table would not see automatic update.

Comment: Okay, now I'm sure I follow you, then. Thanks.